# Thermodynamics, internal energy, state functions

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics

How is internal energy a state function, please provide an explanation

Comment: I don't know why I am not able to understand thermodynamics, I am a student preparing for an exam, please also provide some help in this regard.

Comment: C'mon, show a bit of research effort here. What about e.g. the Wikipedia articles or the standard textbooks is unclear to you?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it shows lack of any research-effort. This type of question is too trivial & can be easily solved by quick googling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How is internal energy a state function?

It is a value for a specific state, not dependent on other states (that is, not dependent on any paths taken leading up to this state). Same goes for mass, volume, temperature etc.

Heat and work are examples of non-state functions since they represent a transition from one state to another.

The term *equation of state* is used for an equation that is only about one specific state / instant in time. For example the ideal gas law:
$$pV=nRT$$

where all variables are evaluated for the same state. And example of an equation which is *not* and equation of state is the energy balance from the laws of thermodynamics:

$$K_1+U_1-W=K_2+U_2$$

Which combines variables from different states.

Comment: What it means by state of system, how to visualise it

Comment: The state of a system or an object is simply the properties of the system in some specific moment. If you look at a boiler in your kitchen, at any instant you could ask yourself, "what is the state of this system". The state would be the volume, temperature, mass, pressure, density, etc. and all similar properties that describe the system without you needing to know anything about the past of this boiler.

Answer (score 1):

A state function is one whose values are dependent on the initial and final states only. Internal energy is a function of temperature, such that only the initial and final temperatures influence the value of internal energy. Wikipedia can help you further.